GW CC : indroducing new LOB to ISO
I am working on GW Claim Center customization. I have already added some new coverage types to data model, and I know how to add appropriate line of data into ISOCoverageCodeMap.csv file.
Now I am working with a new LOB and a new policy type, and I have some coverage types under that new policy type. I have added appropriate lines to ISOCoverageCodeMap.csv, but none of that works, that is, on creation of new exposure, Guidewire's OOTB method ISOTranslate.instance().getCoverageCodes() returns null, like it cannot read the mapping from csv file. Is there something else that I should prepare for new LOB or new policy type, in order to make it work with ISO ?
I have triple-checked my mapping line in csv, and it's fine, LOBCode, PolicyTypeCode, CoverageTypeCode and CoverageSubtypeCode all exist in appropriate ttx files. I have also tried with different lossPartyType values.
I have found nothing in Guidewire's documentation, although I have found articles about ISO integration on a few places.

Is the instance variable null? I found this gosu doc xml in the cc-10.0.3.jar. Is the ISO messaging destination enabled?
<method name="instance">
    <desc>The singleton ISOTranslate instance
&lt;p&gt;
This method only returns a valid ISOTranslate object if the ISO messaging destination is
enabled. If not it will return null. Enabling the ISO messaging destination causes the
server to read and validate the ISO configuration, including the translations, at start up</desc>
    <return>the instance</return>
</method>

OOTB the messaging-config.xml looks like this (disabled).
<destination
      disabled="true"
      id="66"
      initialretryinterval="500"
      internal="true"
      maxretries="5"
      name="Java.MessageDestination.ISO.Name"
      replyplugin="IISOReplyPlugin"
      transportplugin="isoTransport">
      <event
        name="ExposureAdded"/>
      <event
        name="ExposureValid"/>
      <event
        name="ExposureChanged"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimValid"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimChanged"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimResync"/>
      <event
        name="PolicyChanged"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimContactContactChanged"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimContactRoleAdded"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimContactRoleChanged"/>
      <event
        name="ClaimContactRoleRemoved"/>
</destination>


ISOTranslate.instance() returns a correct instance, and the method call .getCoverageCodes() returns null. messaging-config.xml is fine, my destination is not disabled, and mappings for other policy types work fine.

Did you add additional entries into config/iso/TypeCodeMap.xml to map the new policy type and coverages to ISO coverages?

That file is not touched in my customization, its whole content is just OOTB. Since the mapping works for other new policy types, I believe there is no need to put anything there, although I do not understand its purpose.
Sure I would like to try if you have a specific idea about editing of that file.

I think you may be correct that the TypeCodeMap.xml is not required in your case, unless you added a new ClaimCenter losstype that you need to translate to an ISO type. Does the call to getCoverageCodes(policyType, lobCode, coverageType, coverageSubtype, lossCause)return a result for entries in the ``ISOCoverageCodeMap.csv` that were existing OOTB?
